# Downloading multiple files from url using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to download 10,000+ images from a CDN server. However, when I used the following code the script just creates a bunch of empty files and only the last one is downloaded. Also I received tons of errors including MaxListenersExceededWarning and EMFILE, too many open files. How to solve this problem? Thank you.

```
const http = require('https'); // or 'https' for https:// URLs
const fs = require('fs');

for (let i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1497791);
var url = "https://cdnpath.com" + random + ".png";
//var dest = "D:/SavePath/" + random + ".png";

    var file = fs.createWriteStream("D:/SavePath/#" + i + ".png");
    var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file).end();
    });
setTimeout(sleep, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only include relevant code. The issue is that async functions will not block execution thread waiting to end before continuing execution. This makes that you var i will increment in loop and end up with 500 value in less time that it takes to async operations to end, so at the end you only write the last file content

This might fix your issue

```
const saveFile = (counter, rndNumber) => {
    var url = "https://cdnpath.com" + random + ".png";
    var file = fs.createWriteStream("D:/SavePath/#" + counter + ".png");
    http.get(url, function(response) {
            response.pipe(file).end();
    });
}
for (let i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1497791);
    saveFile(i, random);
}
```

This can cause overload issues on the server, so you can do a better approach using async/await or promises in your code, so you can limit the number of concurrent calls to the server.

Comment: Tried this solution  but got 
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:292:11)
    at IncomingMessage.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:726:22)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (internal/streams/readable.js:500:10)
    at flow (internal/streams/readable.js:982:34)

Comment: I edited the example, it looks like the fs.createWriteStream is also an async function and you have to wait the creation is done before calling url and writing response. It would be easier to help if you provide a jsfiddler working example with your code

Comment: TypeError: fs.createWriteStream(...).then is not a function
    at saveFile (D:\Minecraft\app.js:7:63)

Comment: I had a mistake with i variable, Can you try it now? https://replit.com/languages/nodejs I tested it here and seems to work